# Ratio of number of days in which $A,B,C$ finish the work alone

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To complete a certain work, a workman $A$ alone would take $m$ times as many days as $B$ and
$C$ working together; $B$ alone would take n times as many days as $A$ and $C$ together; $C$ alone
would take $p$ times as many days as $A$ and $B$ together : show that the numbers of days in
which each would do it alone are as $m + 1 : n + 1 : p + 1$

I just need hint as how to approach this problem as I am not able to initiate. Please provide some guidance

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Let A do the job in $a$ days, then he does $\frac 1a$ of the job in a day. Similarly define $\frac 1b$ and  $\frac 1c$ and you will obtain 3 equations that you can solve and express $a,b,c$ through $p,n,m$.